# Racket | CLI with specific language

Tags: scheme, command-line-interface, racket

I'm trying to use the `racket` CLI to run a file but I need a specific language (`pretty-big`) features to be available and I'm struggling with that.

As far as I know, if I run `$ racket <file_name>` then it requires the file as a module. In order to do that, I need to add `#lang <some_lang>` at the top of my file, but I just can't find any equiv to `#lang pretty-big`. Any idea how to ask for `pretty-big` this way?

The other option, is to run the code in `load-mode` (from the `racket` CLI manual) but on this case I'm getting no results back which obviously isn't good.

Any suggestions?
I know the solution to this will be super easy, just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search of the [Racket docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/) for "pretty big" turned up [this result](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp/index.html#(part._.Pretty_.Big__.Legacy_.Language_)), which says that the module `lang/plt-pretty-big` corresponds to DrRacket's "Pretty Big" legacy language.

Unfortunately, putting

```
#lang lang/plt-pretty-big
```

at the top of your file won't work, because that module doesn't specify a reader. But you can tell it to use the usual S-expression reader by using the [`s-exp` "meta-language"](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?#(mod-path._s-exp)) as follows:

```
#lang s-exp lang/plt-pretty-big
```

If you want Racket to print out the results of top-level expressions in your file, it looks like the `lang/plt-pretty-big` language still won't do it, and I don't think there's an easy fix. Consider porting the program to `#lang racket`, which has that behavior. Or add `println` around the things you want printed.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to just use `#lang racket` and `(require lang/plt-pretty-big)`?

Comment: @sylewester nope. That's exactly where I stand rn

Comment: @Ryan - my use case here is testing students' assignments. I invoke `racket` via a spawned nodeJS child and await the results. In order to fully test, I'm overriding  OS level I/O operations (such as `display`) with the identity function to retrieve the results. If your solution allows me to retrieve the functions' return value  - I'm good to go. Will test soon :)

Comment: @Ryan - ok, it works. As you said, there is no return value. Hence, I wrapped the function with `display`. Since `display` talks to the I/O, and this whole things run inside a thread - my thread yields the `display` value from its `stdout`. Thanks!